# Determine operator norm of mutiplication operator

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Consider
$$T: (C[-1,1],\|\cdot\|_{2})\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\\Tf :=\int_{-1}^{1}mf\,\mathrm{d}x$$ where $m\in C[-1,1]$.

I want to prove $\|T\| = \|m\|_2$.

$\|T\|\leq\|m\|_2$ can be easily proved by Hölder's inequality,
 how to solve $\|T\|\geq\|m\|_{2}$?

Thank you.

Comment: Find an $f$ with $\|f\|_2=1$ such that $Tf=\|m\|_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $m/\|m\|_2$.$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $